# Red shirt tradition beginning?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

Who first noticed that ST:TOS red shirts were an endangered species? Was it one of the fans or in a forum?

Subsidiary question: did the producers ever talk **contemporaneously** about the phenomena?

Comment: A search of google books would suggest that the term *wasn't* contemporaneous; https://www.google.com/search?q=%22redshirt%22&biw=1360&bih=643&source=lnt&tbs=sbd%3A1%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1960%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F1%2F1970&tbm=bks#q=%22redshirt%22&tbs=sbd:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1960,cd_max:1/1/1970&tbm=bks&start=20

Comment: I've found early references to red shirt deaths in cinefantastique Vol 22 (1991) but nothing much before that. I'd dearly love to get hold of these issues because they've got loads of behind-the-scenes stuff about Star Trek and gay rights; https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=3YRZAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22red+shirt%22+trek&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=shirt

Comment: I doubt it was contemporary. I saw a statistical analysis somewhere that stated yellowshirts had the highest mortality rate.

Comment: When I finally got around to watching TOS, I was surprised to learn that there were almost no red shirt deaths until the second season, so I wouldn't be surprised if no one noticed it at the time, or if it was not even a strong trend to begin with and has been somewhat exaggerated. Much like how Kirk hasn't slept with all that many aliens.

Comment: There is one episode in the first season of TOS that show redshirts dying. *What Are Little Girls Made Of?* Another episode has two yellow-shirts dying at the hands of bigfoot-like creatures, *The Galileo Seven*.

Comment: No red shirt joking in the SNL skit w/ John Belushi from 1976 - http://snltranscripts.jt.org/75/75vstartrek.phtml

Comment: First time I saw this mentioned was in 1981 in The Journal of the Travellers' Aid Society Issue #9, in an article by J Andrew Keith called "The Care and Feeding of NPCs".  The article described the "security guard" archetype, describing the 3 characteristics of the type (1. wearing red shirt; 2. appearing in first few minutes of show; 3. not a series regular or guest star) and how their purpose was to show how the episode threat killed things.  This suggests that this was early in the trope's identification - the author needed to explain the concept and did not call them "redshirts".

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 - seems good enough for an answer?  I'd love to mark it correct unless a better one comes along. :-)