# What's the earliest use of the word/words "Redshirt"/"Red Shirt" to mean "expendable character?

Tags: star-trek, history-of, terminology

In Harry Turtledove's *Three Miles Down* which takes place in 1974, the main character (an SF writer and fan in his early 20s) thinks "The first redshirt down on some new planet didn’t have a prayer of lasting long enough to collect residuals."

Per *Brave New Words* and the [Historical Dictionary of Science Fiction](https://sfdictionary.com/view/2218/redshirt), the earliest use of the words "Red Shirt" (or word "redshirt") to mean the character who is there to die is from 1985 (in "net.star-trek") (thanks to @user14111 for that link).

Surely people had noticed and remarked on the pattern of deaths in ST:TOS long before 1985 and discussed it, but I can't find a reference that confirms this.  Anyone have some 1970s fanzines?

Comment: If you find an earlier one you should communicate it to the Historical Dictionary of Science Fiction site: https://sfdictionary.com/view/2218/redshirt

Comment: Good idea - will do

Comment: Dunno which came first, but in sports it means "someone who officially can be involved but, strategically, is never".

Comment: @msh210 In US college sports, "[redshirt](https://www.northcentralcollege.edu/news/2021/09/13/what-does-redshirt-mean-college-sports)" refers to a scholarship player kept inactive from a team for a year to stretch out their period of eligibility and let them grow and practice more.

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate of this https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139502/red-shirt-tradition-beginning which also has a good 1981 reference in the comments.